# generating query by pandas dataframe from excel files

Tags: python, sql, excel, pandas

I am trying to build an desktop app to generate sql queries from excel through pandas data frame. i am able to generate insert statement , but i am receiving data in time_stamp format, i want convert it into to_date format,please suggest a better way to do this. also please suggest to generate select statement by making use of same code

here is my code:

```
from pandas import *
table_name="ADI"
file_name=pandas.read_excel('supermarke.xlsx')    
def SQL_Insert(SOURCE, TARGET):
    sql_texts = []
    for index, row in SOURCE.iterrows():
        sql_texts.append(
            'INSERT INTO ' + TARGET + ' (' + str(', '.join(SOURCE.columns)) + ')   VALUES ' + str(tuple(row.values))+";")

    return ('\n'.join(sql_texts))
print(SQL_Insert(file_name, table_name))
```

here is my result:-

```
INSERT INTO ADI (ID, Address, City, State, Country, Supermarket Name, Number of Employees, DATE)   VALUES (1, '3666 21st St', 'San Francisco', 'CA 94114', 'USA', 'Madeira', 8, Timestamp('2018-01-12 00:00:00'));
INSERT INTO ADI (ID, Address, City, State, Country, Supermarket Name, Number of Employees, DATE)   VALUES (2, '735 Dolores St', 'San Francisco', 'CA 94119', 'USA', 'Bready Shop', 15, Timestamp('2018-01-12 00:00:00'));
INSERT INTO ADI (ID, Address, City, State, Country, Supermarket Name, Number of Employees, DATE)   VALUES (3, '332 Hill St', 'San Francisco', 'California 94114', 'USA', 'Super River', 25, Timestamp('2018-01-12 00:00:00'));
INSERT INTO ADI (ID, Address, City, State, Country, Supermarket Name, Number of Employees, DATE)   VALUES (4, '3995 23rd St', 'San Francisco', 'CA 94114', 'USA', "Ben's Shop", 10, Timestamp('2018-01-12 00:00:00'));
```

and i am trying to add one more functionality , if file not found shows error message.

excel file

[image: X]

@Chirag, if i have empty cell value i am receiving output like nan, but when i am going to insert this i am not able to insert it because sql use null, instead of nan, any help in this.?

```
INSERT INTO ADI (PLAN_ID, DEVICE_ID, PLAN_CONTRACT_DURATION, DEVICE_CONTRACT_DURATION, SALES_CHANNEL, VENDOR_TYPE, EFFECTIVE_DATE, EXPIRATION_DATE, PLAN_NAME, DEVICE, RRP, DEVICE_REPAYMENT, TOTAL_REPAYMENT_CHARGES, TOTAL_CREDIT_CHARGES, URL, EX_VENDOR_TYPE)   VALUES (20637411, 20663271, 1, 1, 'ALL', 'ALL', Timestamp('2018-10-30 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2050-12-31 00:00:00'), 'Unlimited data Home Wireless ($79 Vividwireless)', 'Huawei B315 ', 0, 0, 199, 0, nan, nan);
```

how to replace nan with NULL/null ?

Comment: Please share your input data in `code-block` not via links or image.

Comment: you should move this question to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @TheCrazyProfessor Why? There is a clear objective stated in this question, it’s not a request for “what could I do better”.

Comment: @MTCoster "please suggest a better way to do this" This made it a code review

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def SQL_Insert(SOURCE, TARGET):
    sql_texts = []
    for index, row in SOURCE.iterrows():
        sql_texts.append(
            'INSERT INTO ' + TARGET + ' (' + str(', '.join(SOURCE.columns)) + ')   VALUES ' + str(tuple(row.values))+";")

    return ('\n'.join(sql_texts))

# check if file exists
if os.path.isfile("demo.xlsx"):
    # reading file
    df = pd.read_excel('demo.xlsx')
    # casting to date as you mentioned
    df["DATE"] = df.DATE.dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    # replacin nan with None
    df = df.astype('object').where(pd.notnull(df),None)
    # generating create table statement, in case if you want to use
    print(pd.io.sql.get_schema(df.reset_index(), 'table_name'))
    # calling your function
    q = SQL_Insert(df, "table_name")
    print(q)
else:
    print("File not found")
```

Output:

```
CREATE TABLE "table_name" (
"index" INTEGER,
  "ID" INTEGER,
  "Address" TEXT,
  "City" TEXT,
  "Country" TEXT,
  "Supermarket Name" TEXT,
  "Number of Employees" REAL,
  "DATE" TEXT
)
INSERT INTO table_name (ID, Address, City, Country, Supermarket Name, Number of Employees, DATE)   VALUES (1, 'Address 1', 'San Francisco', 'USA', 'Maderia', 8.0, '2018-01-12');
INSERT INTO table_name (ID, Address, City, Country, Supermarket Name, Number of Employees, DATE)   VALUES (2, 'Address 2', 'San Francisco', 'USA', 'Brady Shop', 15.0, '2018-01-12');
INSERT INTO table_name (ID, Address, City, Country, Supermarket Name, Number of Employees, DATE)   VALUES (3, 'Address 3', 'San Francisco', 'USA', 'Super River', 25.0, '2018-01-12');
INSERT INTO table_name (ID, Address, City, Country, Supermarket Name, Number of Employees, DATE)   VALUES (4, 'Address 4', 'San Francisco', 'USA', "Ben's shop", 10.0, '2018-01-12');
INSERT INTO table_name (ID, Address, City, Country, Supermarket Name, Number of Employees, DATE)   VALUES (5, None, 'San Francisco', None, "Ben's shop", None, 'NaT');
```

Comment: Hi Chirag,
regarding your answer of converting date , df["DATE"] = df.DATE.dt.date
i don't want specify particular cloumn name in dataframe , its get automatically detected by pandas , i am asking how to convert that in to to-date format

Comment: @adityasingh Can you check now for the None?

Comment: Thanks For your Response.
Can you please suggest a way to replace the timeStamp Format to to_date Format also?
i want date  in to something like this 
TO_DATE('11/30/2018 05:53:13', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
 I am saving result i a file , is it possible to replace date format within output file?